# Load a Child Theme's style.css just before the closing </head> tag

Tags: functions, theme-development, child-theme

I have this in functions.php:

```
<?php

/* Import parent style - The new standard Wordpress way - No @import in CSS! */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_parent_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 20 );
function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'default_stylesheet' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'default_stylesheet' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 99 );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'lovely-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lovely-child-style' );
}

?>
```

It's embedding the parent theme's style on the top of everything, then removing the auto embedded child theme's style.css, then reconnecting the child's style.css again with the prefix name + order that I want. But this last thing is not perfect. This theme using special CSS styling (from the theme admin panel) embedded in the HTML just before the closing /head tag.

How I can go even more belove this and put my child style.css really next to the closing /head tag?

Comment: how is the theme adding that special CSS? you'll have to figure that out before you can determine how to make something appear after it.

Comment: Definitely what Milo said ... I just wanted to add that you can use the dependencies when using wp_enqueue_scripts to force your child theme style to load after your parent theme style. ( see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style )